# Using DCount with Access VBA when table is linked from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm having issues with DCount in an Access 2007 database linking to a SQL 2005 table.

The following code works fine if the table, "`tblPART_CandD_MASTER`", is local

```
DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("[InvalidContract] =0 and [MissingContract] =0  and DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & Me.txtDateTime & "#"))
```

I have moved all of my local tables to a SQL 2005 server. Now, the code above returns zero every time.

If I break the code apart in the following ways it also works:

```
DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("[InvalidContract] =0 and [MissingContract] =0"))

DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & Me.txtDateTime & "#"))
```

As the above two lines of code work, I'm frustrated as to why this wont work:

```
DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("[InvalidContract] =0 and [MissingContract] =0  and DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & Me.txtDateTime & "#"))
```

Comment: When you say does not work, do you mean the count is wrong? Are you sure that there is not a problem with the date format? It is nearly always best to format to a year, month, day format to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: The count is returning zero.  My first inclanation was the date format however if there was a problem with the date format that the code: DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & Me.txtDateTime & "#")) Should return zero as well.  However this works and returns the correct value.  Its driving me insane why the above code works but this code does not DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("[InvalidContract] =0 and [MissingContract] =0  and DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & Me.txtDateTime & "#"))

Comment: I use Access Data Projects and utilize Dcount _ALL_ the time. I don't understand what your difficulty is.

Answer (score 0):

I find that with some fiddling this works:

```
=DCount("*","dbo_tblPART_CandD_MASTER",("InvalidContract=false And MissingContract=false And  DateTimeSubmittedtoDB=#" & [DateTimeSubmittedtoDB] & "#"))
```

The difficulty for me was the bit data type which shows in MS Access as False, even when the value in SQL Server is Null. There are ways around this. I found the problem by running in SQL server:

```
select count(*) 
from tblPART_CandD_MASTER 
where MissingContract=0 
and InvalidContract=0 
and DateTimeSubmittedtoDB={d '2012-09-21'}
```

Comment: Thanks Remou.  I REALLY appreciate your response. Unfortunately, this still isnt working, returning value of zero.  I made changes per your suggestions:
DCount("*", "tblPART_CandD_MASTER", ("[InvalidContract] =false and [MissingContract] = false And DateTimeSubmittedtoDB = #" & [Me.txtDateTime] & "#"))
Based on the data in the table, this should return 3 but only returns 0 .

Comment: What happens when you run a query in SQL Server? Do you get the right results?

Comment: Yes, Remou, I do get correct resultsin SQL and there are no nulls they are all '0' This one really has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

I created a non-elegant solution.  I extracted the pertinent data from the SQL table into a local access table then did the DCount on the local table which worked.  Would have rather not done it this way but I needed to put this issue behind me.  Thanks so much for everyone's input.